# How to plot day in x axis, time in y axis and a heatmap plot for the values in python as shown in the figure?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, heatmap, timeserieschart

I want a heat map plot as can be seen in the attached image
[day in x axis, time in y axis and a heatmap plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eivKk.png)

data- https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av8bxRzsdiR7tEYmXDBWSUKriCSJ?e=m2objJ
I tried plotting the data, but its leading to daily plots of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data is wrapped by row, you need to do some work to `reshape` it into the correct structure. For a 2D Contour like you linked, you need a 2D array of data, so after loading in your data-set, all I did was manipulate it into the correct shape, and then plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

path = r'<your path here>\data.csv'
data = np.array(pd.read_csv(path, header=0, delimiter=',', index_col=None, dtype=float, ))
# print(data.shape) # Gives (8760, 3)

day, hour, value = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]
value = np.reshape(value, (365, len(value)//365))
# print(value.shape) # Gives (365, 24)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols =1, nrows = 1, figsize = (5,5))
ax.set_xlabel('Hour')
ax.set_ylabel('Day')

plot = ax.imshow(value, origin='lower', aspect='auto',
           extent=[hour[0], hour[-1], day[0], day[-1]],
           interpolation='gaussian',
           cmap='jet')

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.84)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.89, 0.125, 0.05, 0.755])
cb = fig.colorbar(plot,  cax=cbar_ax, extend='both', ticks=[0,20,40,60,80,100])
cb.ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='in', size=0)
cb.set_label('Annual AC Power in Year 1 [kW]',rotation=270, labelpad=18)
```

To get

[image: result]

Comment: you are great sir. thanks for finding time to help a stranger on internet.. i will pray to god that may you become the next president or elon musk...

however there was a small error .. i corrected this 

value = np.reshape(value, (24, 365))

you are see that your graph is not the one i attached in my original question, but after the modification its exactly same.. many thanks

Comment: @saikatghosh My mistake! But I'm happy you resolved it. be sure to accept the answer so that other people can be helped by your issue.